# Does anyone know of literature regarding a Neural Net boosted GBM?

Tags: neural-network, predictive-modeling, decision-trees, linear-regression, data-analysis

For obvious reasons, most GBMs created in the private sector are tree boosted.

Occasionally, one might want a linear boosted GBM so that the residual models collapse into a simple linear combination. However, linear boosted GBMs take a lot longer to train.

So what I'm wondering is, has anyone done research on a Neural Net boosted GBM? The model itself would seem to be computationally implausible in almost any use case. But I'm still interested if there has been research on it.